# Снести первые несколько байт с бинарного файла Python

Tags: linux, python-3.x, bash, python-3.5, python-3.6

Суть вопроса такова: Есть WAV файл, необходимо кастрировать его заголовок (первые 44 байта).
Есть ли какие-нибудь способы сделать это быстро (возможно даже не загружая содержимое файла в память), так как очень критична скорость работы скрипта? Увы C и C++ не подходит, задачу нужно решить именно на Python версии 3.6.
Кстати, если есть возможность этот вопрос решить с помощью bash (linux) - вариант тоже приемлем.

Comment: Это технически невозможно по причине особенностей хранения файлов в современных файловых системах. Только перезаписать файл целиком, пропустив первые 44 байта

Comment: Может быть тогда библиотеку какую-нибудь посоветуете? Или способ?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html ?

Comment: Ок. Спасибо! Попробую!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```bsh
tail -c +44 source.WAV > trimmed.wav
```

Comment: Отличное и элегантное решение! То что оно будет с 44 байта брать, это как раз то что нужно. А вывод не будет ограничен, tail же вроде только первые 10 строк выводит, или я ошибаюсь? Я не так давно работаю с linux.

Comment: Последние десять строк — это режим по умолчанию, а в данном случае мы попросили последние байты, начиная с 44-го с начала. :)

Comment: Я linux изучаю уже три месяца и до сих пор удивляюсь насколько эта система помогает быстро и просто решать задачи. Windows просто приставка Dandy рядом с ним. Спасибо большое!!! Всё работает!!! То что нужно!!!

Comment: Ну, к слову, в Win10 серьезных версий можно даже включить встроенную убунту, консоль и икс-сервер, правда, придется ставить отдельно.

Comment: В любом случае - это навеска брони на спорткар. Зачем делать танк из того, что должно быстро ездить? По пятам MacOS им уже не пройти (да там и основа BSD, тоже, конечно Unix подобная и очень приятно со всем стеком команд в разных ОС сидеть). По ходу это начало конца Windows. Плакать не будем :).

Comment: @SergeyRyabov, `man dd` для более классического подхода.

Comment: @SergeyRyabov "вендекапец" говорят с 2003ого года, а она всё жива

Comment: @eri Да разве это жизнь!

Comment: Да вендекапец так-то уже настал... иначе зачем реализация Linux на форточках 10?